# GWT CSS and UI development

Tags: css, gwt

Sorry about longer context before question itself!

I am developer who is fairly new to UI and never had to work extensively on HTML/CSS in past. But my current project I am working on GWT, being aware of Java and basic GWT. I managed to pick up get GWT stuff quickly, but getting stuck from time to time in getting a good UI with CSS for example

- I created Menu using Lable and Tree, but later after few questions on SO realized that Anchor was better choice
- Though I achieved my objective partially with anchors, the UL/LI came in picture in Style

So with that, and my limited current knowledge of CSS,

- Can you suggest me a good tool which can automate style application to GWT elements with a preview?
- Would fundamentals of CSS application be different in GWT as compared to HTML (Specially assuming  my usage of whatever-I-Wished-in-GWT!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, learning a HTML/CSS basics and using [UIBinder](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html) for declaratively creating the UI works best. This way, its quite easy to separate the View and the Controller.

If you're really not into GUI development, try [GWT Designer](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/webtoolkit/tools/gwtdesigner/index.html), which is quite a powerful GUI designer (it let's you design the UI, and then generates UIBinder Files + Java sources for you).

Comment: I have used GWTDesigner extensively. Though there are certain aspects which I need to code after I am done with design in GWTDesigner. I think your point of learning basic CSS is valid.

Comment: I checked the CSS Support in GWT Designer and it looks exnetsive. I think I should be able to get done what I intended to. Thanks for your help again!